# Add custom font to WebStorm on Mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, fonts, webstorm

I find a nice ttf font and want to add it to WebStorm. I tried to import font as a plugin but nothing happened.

Is it possible to add custom font or IntelliJ doesn't support this feature?

Comment: Fonts are reported (handled) by your OS. So .. install font into your OS so you can use system wide (any app)... and then just choose that font in WebStorm / IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: that works, thank you!